# gtk+ menus mouse wheel speed

Tags: c, menu, gtk, mousewheel

I am working on a Grandchild of file-browser-applet in C.

My Problem is that I can't find a Solution to speed up the scrolling with Mousewheel in the Menu. In my case every Mousewheel Click moves only 1/2 entry, what I want is 5 Entries.

The Code:

```
  eintrag->menu = gtk_menu_new() ;
  gtk_signal_connect(GTK_OBJECT (eintrag->menu),"scroll-event",(GtkSignalFunc) scroll_test,NULL) ;

  if ( (n = scandir(parent->full_name,&dir_list,0,alphasort)) > 0 )
     {
     for ( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ )
        {
        eintrag->item = gtk_image_menu_item_new_with_label(eintrag->filename) ;
        ,,,,
        }
     }

  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  gboolean scroll_test(GtkWidget *widget,GdkEventScroll *event,void *nix) 
     {
     g_print("scroll %s %d %d \n",name,event->send_event,event->direction ;
     return FALSE ;
     }
```

The Code is a very simple GTK Menu with a "scroll.event" attached.

The first try was to emit an aditional scroll-event within the scroll_test CB. By using g_signal_emit_by_name(widget,"scroll-event",widget,event,NULL), the result was confusing even if I set a new event struct with new timestamp and ->send_event set to TRUE. Maybe I have here an Error in Parms.

The second Try was to create a gtk_adjustment_new, attach it to the menu with gtk_widget_set_scroll_adjustments and change gtk_adjustment_set_step_increment. No change.

Comment: Too little information, IMO.  What have you tried?  What code is involved?

Comment: I tried to send a second event from event scroll, but earn only crashes. I tried to set an adjustment, it does not work. I tried to use the deltas in gdkscrollevent, but this is only GDK 3, wich is no "standard" installation. I am hopless.

Comment: Probably if you augment your question with the gtk objects you are dealing with, along with your favorite non-working solution (e.g. code), someone might be able to help.  A reference or link to the original or your derived code would be useful as well. Otherwise it seems to be an exercise in mind-reading.